# Complex analysis and differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on complex analysis on the subjects of continuity and differentiation.  I am trying to answer this question, but i am confused with the nomenclature:  what does $f \in H(B(0,1))$ mean?  This is different from all other questions i am answering.

Suppose that $f \in H(B(0,1))$. Define $g : B(0,1) → \Bbb C$ by $g(z) = f(z ̄)$. Using the definition
of the derivative, show that $g \in H(B(0, 1))$.

Comment: Do you really mean $g(z) = f(\bar z)$: how about $g(z) = f'(z)$?

Comment: $H(B(0, 1))$ would generally refer to the set of functions holomorphic on the open disk of radius $1$ centered at $0$.

Comment: I guess you mean $\overline{f(\overline z)}$...

Comment: you are correct

Comment: just to clarify the comment by amsmath is correct

Comment: Just to clarify, correcting your question is not an option, because what?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(z)=\sum a_n z^{n}$ then  $g(z)=\overline {f(\overline {z})}=\sum \overline {a}_n z^{n}$ and the second series has same radius of convergence as the first. Hence $g$ is holomorphic. Alternatively we can verify C-R equations.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, my understanding from above is that If H(z)∈∑anz^n   is there a generic way of describing f(z)

Comment: This answer does not appear to use the definition of the derivative , is there a way of answering this question using the definition of the derivative

Comment: @K.Dawg Write down the real and imaginary parts of $g$ and verify Cauchy -Riemann equations. This shouldn't be difficult at all.

Comment: Thanks Kavi, can i assume that f is differentiable?, then do as you suggested and verify the CR equations.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: @K.Dawg Yes, by definition a holomorphic function on an open set is differentiable at each point.